# OpenGL Texture Mipmaps: Load and Unload

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures, mipmaps

In the perfect case, if the screen resolution is 1024x768, only
786432 texels are needed at a given moment, and 2 megabytes memory
is enough. But in real world there is managing cost, so textures
take much more memory.

Texture streaming could reduce the memory cost of texture, that
is, not all the mipmaps of textures are needed at a given moment.
A texture needs level 0 mipmap because it's near the camera, if
it's far from the current camera, level 5 to 11 mipmaps may be
enough. Camera moves in the scene a while, some mipmaps can be
loaded and some mipmaps can be unloaded.

My question is how to do it effectively.

Say I have a 512x512 OpenGL texture in the scene, so it will has
10 mipmaps. From level 0 to level 9, there are: 512x512, 256x256,
128x128... and 1x1 mipmap. Simplely upload the data like this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGBA8, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p3);
...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

After a while, camera goes far from this texture in the scene,
64x64 mipmap is enough, so the top 3 mipmaps are going to be
unloaded:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p5);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGBA8, 16, 16, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p6);
...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

And then, camera moves towards this texture, 256x256 mipmap is
needed:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 128, 128, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p5);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGBA8, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p6);
...
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

This is just inefficient. Basically it recreates the texture
everytime although the texture id is not changed. PBOs could makes
it faster but the data copying is still cost.

For a 1024x1024 OpenGL texture, can I make it uses only the lower
mipmaps, say level 1 to 9, and leave the level 0 mipmap empty (do
not allocate in video memory) ? In other words: Always keep a
subset of mipmaps from low level to high level. Load or unload
higher level mipmaps without changing the lower mipmaps of a
texture. I think in hardware's perspective this might be possible.

This is what I tried: If I don't call glTexImage2D for level 0
mipmap, this texture may be in an incomplete state. But if I call
glTexImage2D with a null data pointer, it will be allocated in
video memory with zero data (profiling via gDEBugger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal with all of this is limiting the amount of active texture memory you have available, nothing in OpenGL 4.5 is going to help you with that. Reallocation of the texture as a smaller one is a terrible idea (and no, the Unreal engine does *not* do that).

There are two cases where what you are talking about may matter. Case 1 would be what the Unreal engine uses it for: loading performance. It allocates the whole texture, all of its mipmaps, but it only *loads* the lower mipmaps first. This saves time on loading in the level. This can also be used to speed up streaming performance by doing the same thing.

This is done easily in OpenGL 4.5. That's what the mipmap range setting is for; you only load in the lower mipmaps and set the `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` to that range. OpenGL guarantees it will not try to access memory outside of that range.

But dynamically evicting mipmaps from memory is not something that OpenGL 4.5 has a mechanism for.

[ARB_sparse_texture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sparse_texture.txt) however *does*. It allows you to declare that certain mipmaps are "sparse". You allocate storage for them as normal, but you can declare that the higher levels may be evicted from memory. You decide when levels are available by giving them virtual pages. And you can remove these pages, which allows the GPU to use that memory for someone else.

The goal in doing this is, in theory, to be able to use more textures without running out of GPU memory (and thus thrashing). However, you don't really have the tools to be able to do this effectively.

This is because OpenGL doesn't tell you how much memory you have available. Nor does it say how much memory is allocated for buffers/textures. Nor does it say how many of those allocated buffers/textures is currently active and resident on the GPU. So you don't really know when you're close to being about to thrash.

This means that, if you're "close to" a number of large textures, you can still blow memory limits. And OpenGL will not tell you when you've done so.

Even so, this can still be helpful, if you plan your level layouts around it. Oh, and sparse textures are useful for the Unreal engine's case too.

---

> I am thinking about that every mipmap of an OpenGL texture is stored independently, we can attach a lower level mipmap to a texture at runtime, why cannot attach a higher one.

Do not make the mistake of thinking that hardware follows what the API says.

Can you only issue `glTexImage*D` calls to mipmaps other than layer 0? Yes; just use the base/max levels to prevent access outside of the allocated range (that will keep the texture complete).

Will that *guarantee* that the implementation only allocates memory for those particular mipmap levels? No; implementations may allocate mipmap levels outside that range.

Indeed, there's evidence that it doesn't work that way. Consider [ARB_texture_storage](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_storage.txt). This extension, core in OpenGL 4.3+, provides a single function that allocates all of the mipmap levels of the texture at once. So instead of calling `glTexImage2D` for each level, you call `glTexStorage2D` once, and it will allocate all specified mipmap levels for the size you specified. You can leave some off the small range, but not off the top.

This also makes the texture immutable, so you cannot *change* that texture's storage ever again. You can upload to it, but you cannot call `glTexStorage*D` or `glTexImage*D` on it. So no reallocation.

Why would the ARB create an extension who's whole purpose is to prevent you from allocating individual mipmaps, if individual allocations were something that hardware actually supported? And if you think that's a fluke, consider this too.

When ARB_direct_state_access was created, they obviously added DSA-style functions for texture allocation. But notice that they didn't add DSA-style functions to make non-immutable textures; they didn't add `glTextureImage*D`. Their reasoning? "Immutable texture is a more robust approach to handle textures".

Clearly, the ARB sees no value in an API that lets the user say which mipmaps are allocated and which are not.

And it should be noted that nothing in Direct3D *12*, a much lower level API, allows this either. The answer to the question of [how much memory a texture needs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn788680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is [purely a byte-count + alignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn770391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is not a series of byte counts, one-per-mipmap. And [the functions to allocate resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#resource_creation_apis) similarly do not allow expanding mipmaps or anything of the like.

And I even checked Mantle's documentation. It has no facility to have an image's memory be non-contiguous. grBindObjectMemory (the function that associates memory storage with a texture) does not take a parameter specifying the mipmap level.

And for the sake of completeness, neither does Vulkan. It treats an images mipmap pyramid as a single, contiguous block of storage. Sparse images can work, but that works on page boundaries, not at the level of whole mipmaps.

So I would assume nothing about the nature of the hardware based on old OpenGL APIs.

Comment: I used to develop Unreal Engine 3 video games at my previous
company. We got the source code of UE3, so I am very sure UE3 does
do that.

Comment: @amanjiang: If you want to implement UE3-style whatever, and you know that it reallocates textures like that... what exactly is your question? If you want to behave like UE3, just behave like that.

Comment: My question is that could we improve the efficiency on texture
streaming in OpenGL. Unreal Engine just proved the D3D way.  I am
thinking about that every mipmap of an OpenGL texture is stored
independently, we can attach a lower level mipmap to a texture at
runtime, why cannot attach a higher one.

Comment: I will do a research on ARB_sparse_texture, thanks for your help.

Comment: One mipmap image may be stored in many 2D blocks, and every block
of texels is contiguous in memory. To render a geometry, GPU may
sample between the mipmaps of a texture, many 2D blocks of texels may be loaded in cache lines. But, I still think there is no reason
for that several mipmaps of a same texture must be neighbors in
memory.

Comment: That's additional topic. You have just answered my question.

Comment: @amanjiang: "But, I still think there is no reason for that several mipmaps of a same texture must be neighbors in memory." I can come up with a really good reason: hardware. If all mipmaps are contiguous, then the texture mapping unit only needs a single pointer. If they can be in arbitrary memory, the TMU needs a pointer *per mipmap level*.

Answer (score 1):

> so textures take much more memory.

Actually no. *(EDIT) for a 1-dimensional texture* the zeroth mipmap level consumes N bytes, the first N/2, the second N/4, and so on. So the total amount of bytes consumes is

```
sum(i in 0…){ N * 2^-i } = N * sum(i in 0…){2^-i}
```

That's a geometric series which converges to 2. So a mipmaped texture consumes exactly twice the memory of a not mipmaped texture. For a 2D texture it's 1/4th, 1/16th and so on. The larger the dimension of the texture the smaller is the mipmap overhead.

That's not "a lot".

> A texture needs level 0 mipmap because it's near the camera, if it's far from the current camera, level 5 to 11 mipmaps may be enough.

There is no camera in OpenGL and that's not how the mipmaping level is determined. The Mipmap level being used is determined by the rate of change of the texture coordinate in screen coordinates (gradient of the texture coordinate).

> After a while, camera goes far from this texture in the scene, 64x64 mipmap is enough

And maybe you're using the same texture for rendering on a primitive with a very steep texture coordinate gradient (low mipmap level) right after drawing it with a shallow texture coordinate gradient.

> But in real world there is managing cost,

What I'm trying to say is, that the management overhead of trying to properly stream mipmaps is much higher and consumes much more GPU resources, than simply loading all the mipmaps and call it a day.

Also modern GPUs are capable of data fetches on their own; the graphics RAM is just a cache for the system RAM and when you load a texture it actually doesn't go to the graphics memory in the first place. The GPU will fetch the data it needs.

Comment: It takes much more memory than 2 megabytes memory, because there
is not only one texture. A modern video game takes 300 megabytes
memory on textures is not surprised. The Unreal Engine uses
texture streaming technique, and it will recreate a D3D texture
when updating its mipmaps.

Comment: Whatever a texture in video memory, shared memory or system
memory, it costs. On mobile devices the video memory and system
memory is not different. If we could swap the texture mipmaps with
hard disk or external storage, we save memory.

Comment: @amanjiang: The memory overhead for textures is insignificant. Essentially a header of less than a hundred bytes. And the only cost of having a texture around is, that it occupies memory. Memory occupied but not accessed does not impair performance, unless you're running out of memory and the system has to start swapping. The 300MiB+ of texture data games use are not due to overhead, but to the sheer number of textures being used. Texture streaming as used by Unreal Engine is not used for things like mipmapping, but to allow to build massive levels that don't require loading screens.

Comment: @amanjiang: When it comes to OpenGL: Simply don't think about it. Texture management and "streaming" happens automatically, due to OpenGL's machine model. When you load a texture to OpenGL it does not go to graphics memory. It's loaded into the driver's object pool (which may actually be swapped to pagefile). The moment you use a texture on the GPU without it residing in graphics memory (whereever that is) it gets loaded behind the scenes for you. – At least in fully conformant OpenGL implementations.

Comment: @datenwolf: "Simply don't think about it." Which is why the [ARB created an extension that deals with this specific problem](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sparse_texture.txt). Clearly, *someone* is thinking about it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sparse textures address a related, but not identical problem. Also the whole point of sparse textures is to hide the "streaming" scheduling behind regular texture accesses. I'd have assumed, you of all people knew that.

Comment: @datenwolf: If that were the idea, then sparse textures *completely* fails at it. In order to hide streaming "behind regular texture accesses", you have to be able to know when a fetch hit a virtual page that's missing. And to know which page it is. While ARB_sparse_texture_2 provides the former, it doesn't really provide the latter. Nor does it provide a channel for the CPU to find out that such accesses happened. So no, it's not about hiding streaming; it's about controlling whether the texture is all there, which is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: The 1st mipmap level uses N/4 bytes, since it's half the size in each direction. The 2nd N/16, and so on.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Cood catch. However it depends on the dimension of the texture. 1D texture it's (2+d-1)^-i, where d is the dimension.

Comment: Out of memory, it happens. The memory overhead of textures is not
insignificant. On 32bit Windows platform, there is only less than
2GB user address space, big video games may run out the address
space if the engineer don't care about the memory. Any platform
has its limit on memory. And the physical memory amount of mobile
devices is much less than address space, it doesn't swap.

Comment: @datenwolf Texture streaming used by Unreal Engine 3 deals with Mipmapping, I saw the source code, so I am sure.

Comment: @amanjiang: Does it, by any chance load the lower resolution images first, working upwards to the higher levels?

Comment: It could working upwards to the higher levels, or working
downwards to the lower levels.  Two situations. It will create new
one, and copy the reusable mipmaps from the old one. It loads
higher levels from the disk, if it's the upward situation. If you
are interesting in, Unreal Engine 4 is open source on git, look
for ContentStreaming.cpp and FTexture2DResource::UpdateMipCount.